# Disable Leaflet layer check box in a layer control w/ zoom

Tags: leaflet

I would like to have layers listed in my layer control, but have their check boxes disabled when zoomed out beyond a certain level.

I am asking the same question that is found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33696/how-to-disable-overlay-check-box-after-a-certain-zoom-level), but with Leaflet instead of OpenLayers.

This is admittedly a "has this already been done" question. I could try to figure out if it can be translated easily from the OpenLayers example above, but maybe someone has accomplished this already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being a little easier than I expected by using document.querySelectorAll to select checkboxes, and setting them to disabled=true.

Ended up finding help combining [this answer from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25414231/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-radio-button-in-leaflets-layer-control) with [this about iterating over querySelectorAll](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/) (simple for loop).

Ended up with this:

```
var checks = document.querySelectorAll('[type = "checkbox"]'), i;
function disCheck() {
    for (i = 0; i < checks.length; ++i) {
        checks[i].disabled = true;
```

... with some more stuff following it, and calling it in my function that controls zoom stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the [Leaflet layers control](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html) tries to keep things simple. You'll need to extend it to modify functionality to suit what you're trying to do, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `L.Control.Layers` in the following way:

```js
var DisabledLayers = L.Control.Layers.extend({
    onAdd: function(map) {
        this._map = map;
        map.on('zoomend', this._update, this);
        return L.Control.Layers.prototype.onAdd.call(this, map);
    },

    onRemove: function(map) {
        map.off('zoomend', this._update, this);
        L.Control.Layers.prototype.onRemove.call(this, map);
    },

    _addItem: function(obj){
        var item = L.Control.Layers.prototype._addItem.call(this, obj);

        // implement your logic here
        // in this example layers are disabled below zoom 12
        if (this._map.getZoom() < 12) {
            $(item).find('input').prop('disabled', true);
        }

        return item;
    }
})
```

It allows you to implement activation/deactivation logic taking into account individual layers (it is not possible in case of external DOM elements modification).

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/parshin/vgyyzkow/

Comment: True, it would be more difficult to modify individual layers, but I don't need to. Are there other advantages to extending the control over using the method I chose?

Comment: @Tangnar Another advantage I can see is that extended class handles dynamic addition/removal of layers in the control. All others are more theoretical (easy to reuse, all code in one place, etc)...